# How do I get the AWS Cloudtrail records for a particular file on S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS Cloudtrail. I would like to display the audit trail for a particular file on S3 using Python. How do I do this?

Comment: What version of boto are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS CloudTrail **does not keep an audit** of accesses made to Amazon S3 objects.

CloudTrail only records API calls that related to Buckets. See: [Logging Amazon S3 API Calls By Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html)

To obtain information about accesses made to Amazon S3 objects, **enable [Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)**:

> In order to track requests for access to your bucket, you can **enable access logging**. Each access log record provides details about a single access request, such as the requester, bucket name, request time, request action, response status, and error code, if any. Access log information can be useful in security and access audits. It can also help you learn about your customer base and understand your Amazon S3 bill.

Access logs are similar to web server logs, showing each access to objects within Amazon S3.